# Using pyplot for dataframe wrong date (offset by one day)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pyplot for a pandas dataframe to get better control over the axis formatting. The one issue I have come up against is that the date is offset by one day.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


'''
Matplotlib version: '2.1.1'
'''

data = {'test': {Timestamp('2018-02-28 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-04-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-06-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-07-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-08-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-09-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-10-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2019-02-28 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001}}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)

ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=90)
ax.bar(x=df.index, height=df['test'], width=15)

#x axis

months = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
monthFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
```

The resulting chart:

[image: Pic of Chart]

The Dataframe:

[image: dataframe picture]

EDIT: To be clear, I am looking for the dates to show as:
28/Feb, 31/Mar, etc

Comment: What do you mean by "is offset by one day"? The axis shows the ticks at the locations set by the `mdates.MonthLocator()`. And the plot is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I must be misunderstanding how the MonthLocator() works.  I'd like the first tick to show 28/Feb, 31/Mar, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further arguments the `mdates.MonthLocator()` will tick every first of the month. Here it seems you do not want any automatic locations at all, but rather precisely those locations from the dataframe index. This is achieved by setting the `xticks` to those dates,

```
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
```

You may then still use the formatter to get nice ticklabel formatting.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {'test': {Timestamp('2018-02-28 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-04-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-06-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-07-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-08-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-09-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-10-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001,
  Timestamp('2019-02-28 00:00:00'): 84498100.41000001}}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10,5)

ax.bar(x=df.index, height=df['test'], width=15)

#x axis
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
monthFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate( rotation=90, ha="center")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer.  Do you know why we need to ax.set_xticks(df.index) when the x values are set here: ax.bar(x=df.index, ...)?

Comment: The x argument of `bar` determines the position of the bar. `set_xticks` sets the position of the tick. The bar is not equal the tick. Otherwise not sure what you mean.

Comment: I assumed that if we are setting the x of the barchart in ax.bar() that would automatically set the xticks with the appropriate values for the xticks.  I think part of the problem is that when I df.plot, things just work.  Also, I do not recall having to use xticks in all instances of using pyplot for this type of thing in the past.  Thanks for the answer, and point me in the direction of filling some knowledge gaps

Comment: No, matplotlib sets the ticks automatically to useful locations on its axes. This might often lead to coinciding locations for bars and ticks but not necessarily. This is different for pandas bar plots. Pandas puts its bars always at positions 0,1,2, ... N-1 and sets the labels accordingly. Simplified, pandas internally calls something like `plt.bar(range(len(df)), df.values); plt.xticks(range(len(df)), df.index)`.

Comment: Super helpful.  Thanks.